# Send HTTP Request via ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, request

Am trying to send HTTP Get request via C#. But it seems not working. Here is my work. And i wanna from you the corrections needed to make it work !

```
            String Mobile = txt_phone.Text;
            String Message = "You have registered successfuly.";
            Uri targetUri = new Uri("http://sms-om.com/smspro/sendsms.php?user=HatemSalem");
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest) System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
```

Comment: There is no error. But the Http Request seems it is not working. What is the wrong with that code ?

Comment: then what is the data in the request value?  It's probably not null...

Comment: The data are attached with the URL as you see in the code above. "http://sms-om.com/smspro/sendsms.php?user=HatemSalem"

Comment: @Adban: If you look at the address you're using with a browser, you'll get an "Invalid Login" message. Do you expect any different from the HttpWebRequest?

Comment: And i wanna from you the corrections needed to make it work??, downvote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You currently haven't executed the request, use:

```
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

This is the point where it will actually get data from the web and give you any relevent errors

Comment: Great. I had to remove the `as HttpWebResponse`, otherwise was getting an error.
C# is not my area, and just needed this solution for a small thing.
Helped a lot. The question and this answer :)

Answer (score 8):

I do not get an error, but an "Invalid Login" message, which makes me think the form actually makes a Post request instead. Here is a Get Request example anyways:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

        //do get request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create("http://sms-om.com/smspro/sendsms.php?user=HatemSalem");


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
            request.GetResponse();


        Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        string tempString = null;
        int count = 0;
        //read the data and print it
        do
        {
            count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            if (count != 0)
            {
                tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                sb.Append(tempString);
            }
        }
        while (count > 0);
        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: How I can convert it to use on ASP.NET ?